# Checking if a cell is empty on google scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a form in google sheets so that if on column E there's a name (or any non-null value), it checks that the rest of the fields have been filled on columns F, G, H, etc... for this I've made two arrays, one with the values of the column E and the other with the values on the row that is being checked. The problem I'm encountering is with the null condition in the second for iteration

```
var range = R13A.getRange("E7:E15");
var values = range.getValues();

var i = [];
for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++)
{
    if (values[y]!="" && values[y].toString().trim()!="") //here it checks if a name is there
    {
        i.push(y);
        var valRow = Number(i)+Number(range.getRow());
        var range1 = R13A.getRange("G"+valRow+":T"+valRow);
        var values1 = range1.getValues();
        for (var x=0;x<values1.length;x++)
        {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(values1[x]); // this part is just to check what values there are on the cells, it always returns ",,,,,,,," which means the cells actually are empty
            if (values1[x]=="") // And here it should check if on the same row there are any blank cells. **THIS IS THE CONDITION THAT ISN'T BEING MET, WHETHER THE CELL HAS SOMETHING WRITTEN ON IT OR NOT**
            {
                validator = validator+" "+R13A.getRange(String.fromCharCode(7+y)+5).getValue(); //this saves the field names that need to be filled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I check for the values of the cells separately rather than in an array, it does work, which I guess means the problem I have is with my array of data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to check what is the value of `values1[x]` and upon testing, it seems it returns an array.

since `getValues` do return a 2D array, you need to access `values1[x]` as `values1[0][x]` instead since we are always sure that there is only a single row and traverse the columns.

Since your `validator` variable as of now doesn't work, I did simplify it with printing `we have blank cells` instead.

this is the code I tested.

```
  for(var y = 0; y < values.length; y++){
    if (values[y] && values[y].toString().trim()) {
      i.push(y);
      var valRow = Number(y) + Number(range.getRow()); // you used Number(i) here but it should be Number(y)
      var range1 = R13A.getRange("G" + valRow + ":T" + valRow);
      var values1 = range1.getValues();
      for (var x = 0; x < values1[0].length; x++) {               // changed values1 to values1[0] instead
        if (!values1[0][x] && !values1[0][x].toString().trim()) { // changed values1 to values1[0] instead
          Logger.log("we have blank cells");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I simplified some checking on my part, feel free to use or modify it on yours.

Here is the sample sheet:

[image: sample sheet]

Where cells painted with red are blank (8 in total)

and here is the output of the code:

[image: sample output]

As we can see in the output, we were able to count them properly.

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me. I had tried similar approaches but hadn't come up with the answer myself. Thanks again

Comment: @FernandoMiquelCastro, Glad I was of help. Feel free to also upvote my answer if you feel it was useful to you.